# WordPress bug reporting?

Tags: bug-tracking

If you find a WordPress bug, how do you verify that it has been reported and/ or is being worked on for the next release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of evaluating and reporting bugs is documented in Codex under [Reporting Bugs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Reporting_Bugs).